# How to access to Google Chrome History (similar to a REST API)

Tags: google-chrome

Google to provide a manner to working with web serfing history from browser
htttps://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history

But i need to create web-service, that connects to google servers, reads user web-serfing history, analyzes the his interests and make to him some advices.

Is there way to get Google Chrome History?

Comment: The surfing history is (hopefully) a thing private to the browser, not known to Google (only things where google is involved should involve google, you know).

Comment: I have not found answer to my question too. 
I think that my problem can be solved by Chrome extension which collect data from chrome.history and send it to web-service.

Comment: ... which would be horrible, horrible spyware, and which I'd personally ask you **not** to implement.

Comment: ok, it will be my personal tool :)